# Make element tabbable only for screen readers

Tags: html, accessibility, tabindex, wai-aria

Is it possible to make an element tabbable for screen readers only? I know that I can make an element non-tabbable for all devices (`tabindex="-1"`), but is there something like `aria-tabindex`? So I could do the following:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" aria-tabindex="0" />
```

I need this because a client wants a fancy GUI for some normal HTML inputs, and so I'd like to make the inputs themselves non-tabbable (for visual users who can use the GUI), but make them tabbable for non-visual users (who then simply can act on the HTML inputs, and the GUI can be hidden with `aria-hidden="true"`).

**Update**

I found a solution to my specific problem (provide a fancy GUI to visual keyboard and mouse users while not disturbing the experience of screen reader users) in this blog titled [An accessible, keyboard friendly custom select menu](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201111/an_accessible_keyboard_friendly_custom_select_menu/):

The trick is that the native `select` element is placed above the fancy GUI (visually hidden using `opacity: 0`), which itself propagates the received clicks to a custom JS which manipulates the native `select`. This way the GUI doesn't need to be focusable, which solves my problem for this special case. Even text browsers will enjoy the full experience.

I don't know how far this trick can be extended to more complex fancy GUIs, but it's definitely a nice idea.

Answer (score 5):

If you could do this, you would make the form unusable for sighted visitors who have mobility issues that prevent them from using a mouse. They rely on the keyboard in the same way that screen-reader software users do.

You could add keyboard support to the fancy GUI versions, with ARIA used to describe what each part does (ARIA can only describe things, it doesn't add or remove any functionality). I've also seen fancy inputs added as a progressive enhancement over the top of standard inputs, with the graphics just given an aria-hidden=true so they don't appear as duplicates to non-sighted users.

Edited to add: [Filament Group](http://filamentgroup.com/code/) has some styled form inputs in the accessible forms section of their code samples page. They're a good example of what I mean.

Comment: As far as I can see, the mentioned form inputs aren't accessible at all, as they aren't focusable with the keyboard! http://filamentgroup.github.io/checkboxradio/

Comment: The example may not be great (in that case, most there are fine), but the first two paragraphs are accurate, separating keyboard access for screen readers is not an appropriate approach for accessibility.

Comment: Whoops - am on a tablet so couldn't check for keyboard access myself. The issues page seems to indicate its a regression from a previously accessible state.